# Given two services, should I convert the values on source or destination?

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-design

Lets say I have `Service A` and `Service B`.
`Service A` is a crawler that expose its results via an API.
`Service B` eventually consumes `Service's A` data and saves to a DB.

Lets exemplify the problem by saying that `Service A` exposes a field called `created_at`, which is gathered as a timestamp, i.e., an `int`. However, this field needs to be saved as `datetime` at `Service B`.
Should I convert the `created_at` value at `Service A` or `Service B`?

(NOTE: I understand that even if I convert the value at `Service A`, it'll be consumed, at first, as a `str` at `Service B`, but there are built in tools that would do this conversion for free when saving to the DB.)

I'm inclined to convert at `Service A`, because `Service B` is more complex and thus would leave a little more "responsibility" to `Service A`. Just to be clear: I would still check if the data is coming in a proper format at `Service A`, but would not do any type of conversion to adjust it.

Is my view too simplified?

Comment: In microservices, contract the important.Service is having some format for date because of some requirement. If any other service consume service A, then that service is responsible for data conversion not the service A(Parent/upstream). You never know some other service also calling service A and they have some different requirement for date format.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vaibs correctly said, as long as there are no further requirements or constraints to consider, it's better to make data conversion in the consumer (Service B).

Otherwise you could get two drawbacks:

A) Service A has to know all its consumers and their requirements on date conversation.
B) A change in Service B could trigger a change in Service A. The two Services are getting coupled.

In Microservice architectures this situation sometimes is called "pseudo decoupling". Code is splitted in two services but you have to change and release both services together, so you loose one of the main benefits of Microservices, "independent delivery".